# How to calculate the depth of the lake in mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, image-processing, image

I want to calculate mean depth of Goose lake (mean depth=4.6 m), I use bellow command for this operation, But this command is not automatic and we have to create the coordinates manually, and on the other hand, error is high. Can anyone help me improve the command or calculate the depth in another way?

```
GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> {{42.11, 41.72}, {-120.68, -120.04}}, 
 GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image]

Get the coordinates manually

```
lakeContour = {{42.06139018896673, -120.33366857142863`}, \
{42.01901951557524, -120.32489142857145`}, {41.979883050316275`, \
-120.32269714285715`}, {41.94643492712383, -120.34244571428573`}, \
{41.91786775950185, -120.36658285714289`}, {41.86232926116004, \
-120.37755428571428`}, {41.822278941450364`, -120.4126628571429}, \
{41.79856388323117, -120.42692571428573`}, {41.792020253207994`, \
-120.45764571428573`}, {41.825549294948054`, -120.47739428571433`}, \
{41.85334055520192, -120.47849142857147`}, {41.884387091923635`, \
-120.50372571428575`}, {41.912152790705946`, -120.52237714285718`}, \
{41.9350095953905, -120.50811428571433`}, {41.96356908621639, \
-120.49824000000005`}, {41.99048488629956, -120.48617142857148`}, \
{42.01086807025052, -120.48507428571435`}, {42.0459118723763, \
-120.46752000000002`}, {42.06546280322868, -120.4368}, \
{42.078493413349285`, -120.41924571428575`}, {42.08337920245882, \
-120.36877714285716`}};


gcarc = GeoPath[Table[i, {i, lakeContour}], "Geodesic"];
gcarcDistance = 
  GeoDistance[Table[i, {i, lakeContour}], UnitSystem -> "Metric"];
profile = 
  GeoElevationData[gcarc, Automatic, "GeoPosition", GeoZoomLevel -> 4];
pts = profile[[1]][[1]];
depths = #[[1]] & /@ pts;
distances = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
     GeoDistance[{pts[[1]][[1 ;; 2]], #[[1 ;; 2]]}, 
      UnitSystem -> "Metric"]] & /@ pts;
avgDepth = UnitConvert[Quantity[Mean[depths], "Meters"]]
```

out put: 42.0557m

Comment: I don't think [`GeoElevationData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoElevationData.html) has the granularity to find the depth of the lake. I looked at elevation values in the lake's interior and all along its border using its [`Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon). `GeoElevationData` returned the same value for every location, with only a few exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

We can use a combination of [`GeoNearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoNearest.html) and [`Entity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html):

I use the center of your map:

```
pos = GeoPosition[Mean /@ {{42.11, 41.72}, {-120.68, -120.04}}];
```

Find the lake:

```
lake = GeoNearest["Lake", pos][[1]]
```

> ```
> Entity["Lake", "GooseLake::y6htr"]
> ```

Look up its depth:

```
lake["MaximumDepth"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[2.*10^1, "Feet"]
> ```

---

Note that [`GeoEntities`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoEntities.html) can find the lake too:

```
GeoEntities[GeoBoundsRegion[{{42.11, 41.72}, {-120.68, -120.04}}], "Lake"]
```

> ```
>  {Entity["Lake", "GooseLake::y6htr"]}
> ```

Comment: While this is a good way to utilise inbuilt features - the data is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I answered something similar on the Wolfram Community - and I've found a way to counteract the problem faced by GeoElevationData.

Firstly, your code has a bug. The depths data should be

```
depths = #[[3]] & /@ pts;
```

instead of

```
depths = #[[1]] & /@ pts;
```

Also, I've realised that you can just do

```
Mean[GeoElevationData /@ GeoPosition /@ lakeContour]
```

Now, since GeoElevationData takes the average elevation - not the average depth. So in order to combat this, pick a random point very close to the lake and subtract the average height of the lake from it. This should give you the desired result.